# How to setup iOS with ShareKit and OAuth

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, sharekit

I have setup my config for twitter as described in the documentation. I setup bitly and all other things. I even made a change to ShareKit to use https and api.twitter.com.. But I am still getting "Could not authenticate with OAuth" error.

Any idea what to check next?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes what is wrong is the authentication 'saved' into iPhone, and you must relogin.

See: https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/89